# Why cycles in cause chain do get used?

Tags: java, exception

I've just read that "some SqlExceptions thrown by Oracle jdbc drivers has reference to itself in cause field". IMHO an exception can cause itself about as easily as I can [pull myself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) out of a swamp by my hair.

But this seems to be normal, even `Throwable.printStackTrace` recognizes a "CIRCULAR REFERENCE", and that's the only such place in JDK I know about (e.g. all `Arrays.deep*` methods end up with a stack overflow for recursive structures).

So what's the reason for creating cycles in the cause chain?

Comment: Well you'd have to ask the authors at Oracle. Just a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cause==this` means that no cause has been initialized.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1173#c12) `getCause()` will return `null` in such a case. The code in `Throwable.printStackTrace` exists to handle multi-element loops. I don't think there's any good reason for such loops, but maybe some got in due to bugs or malice.